# What has Montblanc Noland done for the Tontatta Kingdom for him to be called a hero?

Tags: one-piece

Dwarves from Tontatta Kingdom said that Montblanc Noland is like a hero for them, but what has he done for them that makes the dwarves say that he's a hero?

Any explanation from manga or anime?

Comment: Montblanc gave pumpkins to the tontatta kingdom - just kidding

Comment: @krishna-Itachi'sfan lol, it's not skypiea xD

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[image]

```
                         From One Piece Chapter 713 Page 19
```

From the [Wikia article on Montblanc Noland](http://onepiece.wikia.com/wiki/Montblanc_Noland):

> Sometime in his journeys, he entered the New World and encountered the island of Green Bit, protecting the Tontatta Kingdom and its people from the humans who were ravaging their homes. However, Noland's tales would forever be labeled lies after one unlucky event around a friend he made.

Unfortunately, this is all we know about Noland's act which earned him the title of a "hero".